# Does has_secure_password prevent mass signups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in the process of creating my user model, it occurred to me that it's seemingly trivial for someone to create a script that makes users en masse.

Does has_secure_password, or rails somehow handle it? If yes, how? If not, What do you suggest I implement? (something other than a captcha much preferred)

Comment: .. are you getting mass signups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that module does not prevent it. It only handles the storage of encrypted passwords and authentication. It does not even provides any controller action for signups.

Rails itself does not provide any feature.

In order to limit the mass signups there are several solutions, depending on your business. For instance, you can

- integrate a captcha solution such as [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)
- ask the user to solve a trivial quiz or math calculation
- ask the user to confirm the account by sending an email address with a link to click
- ask the user to enter a credit card to validate the account